# how to iterate over multiple arrays of parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to iterate over the arrays and pass the values as parameters to the method.

```
function getAll() {
   urls = [contactUrl, accountUrl, assestUrl];
   nodes = ['#contactData', '#accountData', '#assetData'];
   list = [$noContacts, $noAccounts, $noAsset];
   //Todo
   search(url, node, list);
}
```

e.g.: in first iteration: `search(contactUrl, '#contactdata', $noContacts)`

What is the best way to handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just go the simple way:

```
for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    search(urls[i], nodes[i], list[i]);
}
```

Of course, that considers your arrays are of the same length. If you want to go as far as your shortest array, you could also do:

```
const len = Math.min(urls.length, nodes.length, list.length);
```

And then iterate until `i < len`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the arrays are the same length:

```
urls.forEach((url, index) => {
  search(url, nodes[index], list[index]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would want an array of search result returned back. In this case you can use map function like this

```
function getAll() {
   urls = [contactUrl, accountUrl, assestUrl];
   nodes = ['#contactData', '#accountData', '#assetData'];
   list = [$noContacts, $noAccounts, $noAsset];
   return [...urls.map((url, index) => search(url, nodex(index), list[index]))]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go the simple iteration route as other answers mention. However, that requires the arrays to all be the same length, but more importantly, this seems like the perfect opportunity to refactor a bit. If these three arrays are so tightly coupled and correlated by index, perhaps they should be turned into a single array of objects instead?

```
function getAll() {
    let searches = [
        { url: contactUrl, node: '#contactData', list: $noContacts },
        { url: accountUrl, node: '#accountData', list: $noAccounts },
        { url: assetUrl, node: '#assetData', list: $noAsset },
    ];
    searches.forEach(item => {
        search(item.url, item.node, item.list);
    });
}
```